# MySQL - SELECT based on repetitions in one column meeting requisites in another

Tags: mysql, sql

For two columns; person and clothing;

```
person    clothing
A         shirt
B         shoes
A         pants
A         shoes
```

how do I SELECT only people who have all three types of clothing (shirt, pants and shoes) to give back:

```
person
A
```

EDIT: I'm wondering if there is some sort of iteration that can be done

i.e `return person if for (i=0, i<number of rows, i++) all three types are found.`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another solution (not such fancy as the Gordon's one) is to use some kind of mysql intersection.

```
SELECT DISTINCT pc.person  
FROM personclothing pc
INNER JOIN personclothing pc2 on pc.person = pc2.person AND pc2.clothing  = 'shirt'
INNER JOIN personclothing pc3 on pc.person = pc3.person AND pc3.clothing = 'pants'
INNER JOIN personclothing pc4 on pc.person = pc4.person AND pc4.clothing = 'shoes'
```

or using `IN`

```
SELECT pc.person  
FROM personclothing
WHERE person IN (SELECT person FROM personclothing WHERE clothing  = 'shirt') AND
      person IN (SELECT person FROM personclothing WHERE clothing  = 'pants') AND
      person IN (SELECT person FROM personclothing WHERE clothing  = 'shoes')
```

**EDIT** based on comment. If you need persons having `shirt` and one of those: `pants` or `shoes`

```
SELECT pc.person  
FROM personclothing
WHERE person IN (SELECT person FROM personclothing WHERE clothing  = 'shirt') AND 
     (        
        person IN (SELECT person FROM personclothing WHERE clothing  = 'pants') OR
        person IN (SELECT person FROM personclothing WHERE clothing  = 'shoes')
     )
```

Comment: Thank you! Do you know how I could instead do this for "OR" here? For example: The person has a shirt AND either Pants OR Shoes

Comment: @GabrielVega It is definitely possible in the second solution. See the edit.

Answer (score 2):

One method is:

```
select person
from personclothing
where clothing in ('shirt', 'pants', 'shoes')
group by person
having count(distinct clothing) = 3;
```

If you have no duplicates, then using `count(*)` instead of `count(distinct)`.

Answer (score 1):

Another method is:

```
select 
person, 
count(distinct(clothing)) as clothing_count
from 
personclothing
where 
clothing in ('shirt', 'pants', 'shoes')
group by 
person
having 
clothing_count = 3;
```

Comment: This will give an additional column in result-set though. You may ignore that column.